# Keep a forward slash and make superscripts with timePlot from package openair

Tags: r, plot, superscript

How can I keep a forward slash in R?

For instance, I need to keep the slash and make the 3 superscript,

```
...
ylab = "PM2.5 Concentration [ug/m3]/ Device Humidity [%]",
name.pol = c("PM2.5 Concentration [ug/m3]", "Device Humidity [%]"),
...
```

I get this result automatically,

[image]

The slash in front of **m** has been removed (**not** what I want).

The 3 is a superscript (what I want).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
            timePlot(allData, 
               pollutant = c("particle_concentration", "humidity"), 
               avg.time = mean,
               lwd = 2,
               lty = 1,
               ylab = "PM2.5 Concentration [ug/m3]/ Device Humidity [%]",
               xlab = siteData$description,
               name.pol = c("PM2.5 Concentration [ug/m3]", "Device Humidity [%]"),
               cols = c("blue", "orange"),
               type = "site",
               group = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not a scientist. the scientist asked me to do so and requested that to happen I'm afraid....

Comment: see my edit above. what else are needed to show then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `auto.text = FALSE`  and use `plotmath`:

```
library(openair)
timePlot(mydata, pollutant = "nox",
         ylab = expression(paste("PM2.5 Concentration ", group("[", mu*g/{m^3}, "]"), "/ Device Humidity [%]")),
         auto.text = FALSE)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks Roland for the help!